# Show that $f(x) = x$ if $f(f(f(x))) = x$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is strictly increasing, show that $f(x) = x$ if $f(f(f(x))) = x$.

So this compulsorily ESTABLISHES that $f(x) = x$ only, and no other solution. So, merely substituting $f(x) = x$ and hence showing the given equality holds will not earn any credit.

I was proceeding via inverses, but then I got confused with the notation. And for that, the problem got tricky.

Comment: Where exactly did you stumble? We won't do the problem for you, just help you over the bump.

Comment: I think the elegance of the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x_0)>x_0$ for some $x_0$. Then 
$$
f(f(f(x_0)))>f(f(x_0))>f(x_0)>x_0,
$$
contradicting the hypothesis that $f(f(f(x_0)))=x_0$. We get a similar contradiction if $f(x_0)<x_0$. So the only option is that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: You mean "we get a similar contradiction of $f(x_0) < x_0$" I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really helpful.

Comment: @Frank: indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If f is strictly increasing, then if x>y, f(x)>f(y).  Suppose f(f(f(x)))=f(x).

Case 1: Suppose $f(x) < x$.  So, $x>f(x)$.  Thus, $f(x)>f(f(x))$ since $f$ is strictly increasing.  It then would follow that $f(f(f(x)))>f(f(x))$, since $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$.  But, since f is strictly increasing we can also infer that $f(f(x))>f(f(f(x)))$.  Thus we have a contradiction and it is not the case that $f(x) < x$.

Case 2: Suppose $f(x)>x$.  The reasoning of this case comes as similar to that of case 1.  So, it does not hold that $f(x)>x$.

By trichotomy it follows that $f(x)=x$

Comment: Thank you. The elegance was eluding me.

Comment: +1 for "trichotomy". People have lost classy talk these days.