# Given continuous function s.t. $f(f(f(x))) = x,$ prove/disprove $f$ is the identity function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the relation:
$$f(f(f(x))) = x, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Prove/Disprove: $f$ is the identity function.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060904/prove-or-disprove-that-f-is-identity-function-given-that-f-is-continuous-and?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is one-to-one, so it is either increasing or decreasing.  But if $f$ were decreasing, $f \circ f \circ f$ would also be decreasing, so it must be increasing.
Now if $f(x) > x$ we'd have $x < f(x) < f(f(x)) < f(f(f(x)))$, and similarly with inequalities reversed.