# $f(f(f(x)))=x,$ but $f(x)\neq x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing function such that  $f(f(f(x)))=x$ then by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718327/show-that-fx-x-if-fffx-x) $f(x)=x.$ Does the result fail if we drop the hypothesis that f is strictly increasing? 
I find such an example if I change the domain and codomain to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f=rotation \ by\  120^o,$ but could not think of a map from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}.$ 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb{R^1}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ be a one-to-one mapping (which exists, because both sets have the same cardinality). Now set $f=g^{-1}\circ F\circ g:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1$, where $F$ is the rotation by $120^\circ$. So the result is not true: this is the desired counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean one-to-one and onto? Otherwise $g^{-1}$ doesn't make sense

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes, sure.

Answer (score 4):

Define $f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x \not\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can make $f$ act as a 3-cyclic permutation

$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x = -1$ } \\
1  &\text{if $x = 0$} \\
-1 &\text{if $x = 1$} \\
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

I suppose it's also possible to make a continuous version of this.

Comment: Continuous is not possible, because then f would be increasing.

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid guess. Can I ask you why it would be increasing?

Comment: Agree with @user345777 $f$ is obviously a bijection. A continuous bijection from $\Bbb{R}$ to itself is either increasing or decreasing. The 3-fold iteration of a decreasing function is itself decreasing which is absurd. So it must increasing and that case has been handled.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow yourself to consider the projective line (i.e., the reals with a point at infinity), then the function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
is a nice continuous solution to the problem (although you have to make sense of "continuous" for this extended line). Pierre Samuel's book on *Projective Geometry* has a nice exposition of this around page 58.

(By the way, this answer was inspired by @DonaldSplutterwit's deleted answer, although I *might* have stumbled on it myself, since I've been thinking about projective geometry and looking at Samuel's book today anyhow. Thanks, Donald!)

Comment: Then you could "cram $\infty$ into $\mathbb{R}$" using a variant of the infinite hotel paradox if you really wanted to, and then apply the same sort of construction as in Vladimir's solution.  Of course, that won't result in a continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.